# Terminal: Permission denied when trying to install APBS binary

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to follow this guide to build the APBS software :
https://github.com/Electrostatics/apbs-pdb2pqr/blob/1.4.1-binary-release/apbs/BUILD.md

after downloading the binary from:
https://github.com/Electrostatics/apbs-pdb2pqr/tree/1.4.1-binary-release

> Create a directory within which to build APBS.
>
> ```
> cd <APBS>/apbs
>
> mkdir osx
>
> cd osx
> ```

and I'm getting:

```
Turkis-MacBook-Pro:~ Turki$ cd <APBS>/apbs

-bash: /apbs: Permission denied
```

I never used the terminal before. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd <APBS>/apbs
```

You have to give the correct path to apbs directory. What is given in the command (APBS in angle brackets) is just a place holder. Either you have to give the complete path or relative path with respect to your current directory.

The below given link will give you some info.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20520?viewlocale=en_US